# media-scanner-service consumes 100% CPU on Bq Aquarius

Tags: 14.10, ubuntu-touch, sd-card, phone, media-manager

I have have something like 10 Gigs of music on my SD card and media-scanner-service takes 50%-100% of CPU constantly. Rebooting or waiting doesn't help. I think it shouldn't take several days to scan it. Actually the music do appear in the player, but media-scanner-service never stops. If I remove the card media-scanner-service goes away. This might be a reason for relatively poor battery life. Does anyone have this same problem?

Comment: Oh no, on the phone, too? I hate this whenever it occurs on my laptop, but now also on the phone? -___-

Comment: Yes, unfortunately at least on my phone. On the other hand it would be great if disabling media scanner would improve battery life :)

Answer (score 0):

It's [known, yet unresolved but](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mediascanner2/+bug/1398614) with a possible, temporary workaround: place a file called .nomedia in the root directory of the SD card once all the media is scanned and remove it when you need to add some media. Place it back when all the media is found again. I can't, however, verify if this works, since I haven't used a SD card with a lot of media yet and therefore don't have the issue. If it doesn't work, you need to wait for the bug to be fixed (or fix it, if you know enough to fix it.)